# Convert FieldInfo to PropertyInfo or vice versa

Tags: c#

I have a class with `Component target`, `string propertyName`, `FieldInfo mFieldInfo` and `PropertyInfo mPropertyInfo`, where `mPropertyInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty(property);` and `mFieldInfo = target.GetType().GetField(property);` and i use one of these variables, which not null. And i want to use only one variable `mProperty`, which can be setted by PropertyInfo **OR** FieldInfo. I can't use properties everywhere because my code gets properties and fields also from not my classes.

Comment: Use MemberInfo as the type for mProperty as FieldInfo and PropertyInfo derive from it, because fields and properties are class members. Also your single variable should not be called mProperty if it can contain field infos, because fields are not properties and vice versa.

Comment: `FieldInfo` and `PropertyInfo` both inherit from `MemberInfo`, can you use that?

Comment: I was tried use MemberInfo, but i can't get and set value with this and it's my goal. I also know that fields are not properties. I just don't invented better name. In code context this name is understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use these extensions to get either:

```
public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
    t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();

public static List<string> GetPropertyOrFieldNames(this Type t) => t.GetPropertiesOrFields().Select(mi => mi.Name).ToList();

public static MemberInfo GetPropertyOrField(this Type t, string memberName, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
    t.GetMember(memberName, bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).Single();
```

Then use these methods to manipulate the `MemberInfo`s:

```
// ***
// *** MemberInfo Extensions
// ***
public static Type GetMemberType(this MemberInfo member) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            return mfi.FieldType;
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            return mpi.PropertyType;
        case EventInfo mei:
            return mei.EventHandlerType;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or EventInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}

public static bool GetCanWrite(this MemberInfo member) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            return true;
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            return mpi.CanWrite;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo or PropertyInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}

public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
        case MethodInfo mi:
            return mi.Invoke(srcObject, null);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or MethodInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}
public static T GetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) => (T)member.GetValue(srcObject);

public static void SetValue(this MemberInfo member, object destObject, object value) {
    switch (member) {
        case FieldInfo mfi:
            mfi.SetValue(destObject, value);
            break;
        case PropertyInfo mpi:
            mpi.SetValue(destObject, value);
            break;
        case MethodInfo mi:
            mi.Invoke(destObject, new object[] { value });
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or MethodInfo", nameof(member));
    }
}
public static void SetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object destObject, T value) => member.SetValue(destObject, (object)value);
```

Comment: I was hoping for a different solution, but thanks! I tried to come up with something similar, but I didn't succeed. I was known about MemberInfo, but I probably didn't understand how it works. Thanks again.

Comment: @ПегасЕвгений I too am disappointed that .Net doesn't include better `MemberInfo` based capabilities, but this isn't too onerous. Reflection is slow in general anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can create property with the base type of both of them :

```
MemberInfo mProperty { get; set; }
```

and then assign :

```
mProperty = target.GetType().GetProperty(property);
```

and also :

```
mProperty = target.GetType().GetField(property);
```

See also :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.memberinfo?view=netcore-3.1#properties

Comment: This is not what I needed